# Sandwhich/Squeeze theorem for (1/n)tan(1/n)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to use the sandwhich/theorem to show that:
$\frac{1}{n}\tan\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $ n \to \infty $

I'm not sure how to do this. I understand how to use the theorem to prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $, but that used the fact that the $-1 \le \sin\frac{1}{n} \le 1$, so I'm not sure what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$0\leq\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\tan\left(1\right)$$
 then $$0\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\tan\left(1\right)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You should use the fact that $\cos \alpha \geq 1/2$ provided that $\alpha$ is sufficiently close to $0$. Then write
$$
\tan \frac{1}{n} = \frac{\sin (1/n)}{\cos (1/n)}.
$$

Comment: That fact about cos has never been mentioned in class before so I am reluctant to use it. Is there any other methods?